# Evaluate $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{a^n + n^b}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

Evaluate $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{a^n + n^b}$, $a > 0$, $b \in \mathbb{R}$

I've tried to use squeeze theorem:
$$\sqrt[n]{n^b + n^b} = \sqrt[n]{2n^b} = (2n)^{\frac{b}{n}} = 1 < \sqrt[n]{a^n + n^b} < \sqrt[n]{2a^n} = \sqrt[n]{2} \times \sqrt[n]{a^n} = a$$
Not what I am looking for.

Generally, intuition is based on experience (and I don't have it much), but I assume (bad assumption though), that this limit equals $a$, since $a^n$ grows faster, than $n^b$, which means $n^b$ can be neglected (perhaps).
For $a > 1$ next is viable option:
$\sqrt[n]{a^n+n^b} = \sqrt[n]{a^n\cdot(1 + \frac{n^b}{a^n})} = a\cdot \sqrt[n]{(1 + \frac{n^b}{a^n})}$
But not for $a \in (0, 1)$, since in this case $a^n \to 0$, so $\frac{n^b}{a^n} \approx \frac{n^b}{0}$, so it is unknown, how it will behave inside of the n-root.

But of course I haven't found any proofs or explanations on this problem. Maybe I have been unlucky.
Hope this question won't be too boring to you.

Comment: You will get different values for $a\leq1$ and for $a>1.$ Your argument for the squeeze theorem assumes $a^n>n^b,$ which assumes $a>1.$

Comment: If $a <1$, you can use squeeze theorem by noting $n^{b/n} \leq (a^n + n^b)^{1/n} \leq (n^b + 1)^{1/n}$.

Comment: For $a>1,$ use: $$a^n<a^n+n^b<a^n+a^n$$ for large $n,$ and apply the squeeze theorem.